# Is it possible to repackage macos app store app?

Tags: applications, time-machine, mac-appstore, restore

I have a MacOS App Store app that I *depend* upon, almost on an hourly basis, that is no longer available in the app store (or anywhere else for that matter). I've been tried contacting the original developer on multiple occasions on multiple platforms for almost three years, to no avail. I have even offered to purchase it from them -- my only guess is that the developer has either gone off the grid or, I hate to think it, is no longer living. There are no suitable substitutions available.

I am able to continue using the app if I restore my computer from a time machine backup, but I desire to do a clean install of Big Sur because my machine has collected a lot of cruft over the last 3 years (ahem, node_modules) and would like to know if it is possible to self-package an app from the App Store in order to re-install it myself.

I have some programming knowledge and have tried a couple of things, including copying what I could determine as the application files from "Applications" and "Library" from the backup to the new computer, but unfortunately this did not work and I am unfortunately a bit of a novice when it comes to Mac apps.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Which application is this?

Comment: Copia: https://www.producthunt.com/posts/copia-for-mac